# IllegalArgumentException on Pyspark + Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, anaconda

I recently installed Pyspark on my Windows 10 machine by running the following:

```
conda install pyspark
```

Looked like it installed fine and I could import it, I ran this code on a jupyter-notebook

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
import os, sys
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('app').getOrCreate()
file = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'file')
```

But as soon as I ran this:

```
dataset = spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').load(file)
```

I got the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'Can not create a Path from an empty string'
```

What could be causing this error? If I search the error itself I get into multiple unrelated errors, and I'm very new to spark so, I don't even know what to google to be more specific on my search, any pointers on how I can troubleshoot this would be very appreciated.

**Edit**: I'm adding the full stack trace of the error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o203.load.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getParent(Path.java:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.ancestorIsMetadataDirectory(FileStreamSink.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$1.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$anonfun$1.apply(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterImpl$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:248)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterNot(TraversableLike.scala:267)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterNot(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$createInMemoryFileIndex(DataSource.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-1c28b73fcdcb> in <module>
----> 1 dataset = spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').load(folder)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    164         self.options(**options)
    165         if isinstance(path, basestring):
--> 166             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    167         elif path is not None:
    168             if type(path) != list:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: 'Can not create a Path from an empty string'
```

Comment: Can you please add the full call stack trace we can can see which part of the dataset line is causing the error?

Comment: @gregory There you go.